# How to use datepicker value in main activity?

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to use a datepicker in my app. I followed the steps from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html and developed the app.

It has a method which is called when the date is picked.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"The date is: " + year + month + day ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
```

Now I want to use the date in main activity. The above method is in different class:

```
   package com.example.shiza.cube26;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Shiza on 04/10/2015.
 */
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"The date is: " + year + month + day ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

I want to get the value form onDateSet to the MainActivity. How can I do that? Please help me to solve this.

Edit 1:

I am using the sharedprefrences to solve the above issue:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Toast.makeText(this,"I am in on resume",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("DATE_OF_JOURNEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    date = sharedPreferences.getString("DATE_OF_JOURNEY",null);
    if ( date  == null )
    {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("DATE_OF_JOURNEY", day + "/" + month + "/" + year).apply();
    }

    date_text.setText(date);


}
```

I am writing date like this:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("DATE_OF_JOURNEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"The date is: " + year + month + day ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("DATE_OF_JOURNEY", day + "/" + month+"/"+ year).apply();
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
```

But,still above code is not working?

Comment: Create a `interface` in your `DatePickerFragment` and implement that in your `MainActivity`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: yes but you can read the documentation about communicating fragments with activity here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Is there any other to achieve it?

Comment: yes using `BroadCastReceiver`

Comment: does the main activity contain this fragment?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `SharedPreferences` and save your year, month and day there. Then read values in `onResume()` callback of your MainActivity.

Another option is to create an interface in your DatePickerFragment and implement this interface in your MainActivity.

**EDIT**:
Also you can create custom [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), then send a message in `onDateSet()` and receive it in your `MainActivity`

Comment: Is there any other to achieve it?

Comment: You can also create intent with year, month and day as extras and start MainActivity in onDateSet() but SharedPreferences is better approach

Comment: yeah, that's why SharedPrefs or interface are better

Comment: Try using getDefaultSharedPreferences